# How to Load Views from Custom Assembly in .NET6 MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I am trying to load category specific views from **BookWebApp.Category.HTTP** assembly into the main web app that is **BookWebApp.UI**.

Tried this thing until now.

1. ViewLocationFormats.Add()
2. presently using custom View location Expander [Image 2]

I have added a project reference of BookWebApp.Category.HTTP into BookWebApp.UI application. Also Added the custom category library into Service Collection.

The category Controller is working properly but not loading the category-specific views. I am working using .NET6 MVC. Thank you.

[image: Project Structure]

[image: Custom View location Expander]

[image: View not found error]

Edit: -
I Have already added following code.

This code is in `ConfigureCategoryController.cs` file inside `BookWebApp.Category.HTTP` assembly.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddCategoryRazorViews(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(option =>
    {
          option.ViewLocationExpanders
                .Add(new CategoryViewLocationExpander());
            
    });
    return serviceCollection;
}
```

This code is in the Program.cs in `BookWebApp.UI` startup project. I am using .NET6 MVC. So there is no StartUp.cs

```
builder.Services.AddCategoryRazorViews();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddCategoryController();
```

Edit 2:- Category Controller

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
        private readonly ILogger<CategoryController> _logger;
        private readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;

        public CategoryController(ILogger<CategoryController> logger, ICategoryService categoryService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _categoryService = categoryService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var categoryVM = await _categoryService.GetAllCategoriesAsync();
            if (categoryVM == null)
                return NotFound();
            return View(categoryVM);
        }
}
```

Edit 3:

```
public static IMvcBuilder AddCategoryController(this  IMvcBuilder mvcBuilder)
    {
        mvcBuilder
            .AddApplicationPart(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(CategoryController)))
            .AddControllersAsServices();
        return mvcBuilder;
    }
```

Comment: What kind of project SDK is the **BookWebApp.Category.HTTP**: `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` or `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor`?

Comment: It is Microsoft.NET.Sdk

Comment: Change it to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` and try it. I don't know in FULL details the difference, but at least I know in order to work with razor files from another assembly (for them to be compiled, copied etc. etc.) you need the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor`.

Comment: I have tried it but it is not working. It is displaying error 404. Displaying "No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7208/Category"

Comment: Have you registered the **CategoryViewLocationExpander** in the service collection (Startup.cs)? `services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new CategoryViewLocationExpander()));`

Comment: Yes, I have already added the required code to the projects. I have updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: Kindly include the code of controller/action which you are trying to show (the CategoryController)...

Comment: I have updated the question with the Category Controller code. Please look into Edit 2 section.

Comment: Have you configured the `ApplicationPart` to include the controller(s) from your custom assembly? I see you call a `services.AddCategoryController...` but I don't know what it is...basically you have to do: `services.AddControllersWithViews().AddApplicationPart(_the_BookWebApp.Category.HTTP_assembly_)...`

Comment: Yes, I have done that too. I have created a custom class to configure CategoryController. I have updated the question with configured code. Please look into Edit 3.

Comment: @SPSarkar, Can you create a simple sample to reproduce the problem and share it with us, so that we can directly according to your code to test it? Besides, you can create a Razor class library and directly use it in the MVC application, refer to [Working with Razor Class Libraries in ASP.NET Core](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/razor-class-library) and [Create reusable UI using the Razor class library project in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: I have done many times using controllers/razor pages from another assembly and it works with the above setup, with the exception of `CategoryViewLocationExpander`. I don't recall ever doing something like that. Maybe that's the part that is messing up the rest of the code. Maybe try to comment it (just comment the call to .`AddCategoryRazorViews`) ?